# Get 2 in 2 elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm beginner and have one question.

I have one um array and need show just 2 in 2 elements of array elements, my code is:

```
var datas = [];

followTotalsData.forEach(function(dataByDay) {
    datas.push(dataByDay[1]);
});


datas = [1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

But I need the array formated as

```
var newDatas = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

Comment: test if each items of your array are even numbers, if not delete them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as

> How can I only get *Numbers* that are multiples of `2` from my *Array* of *Numbers*

Use the remainder operator `%`.
If `x % y` is `0` then `y` divides `x`.

```
var datas = [1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var newDatas = datas.filter(function (e) {return e % 2 === 0;});
// [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
var followTotalsData = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 
var result=[];

followTotalsData.forEach(function(data) {
    if (data % 2 == 0 ) result.push(data);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every other element of the array, use the modulus function on the index of the array:

```
var datas = [1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var newDatas = datas.filter(function (e, index) {return index % 2 === 1;});
// [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

var newDatas = datas.filter(function (e, index) {return index % 2 === 0;});
// [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```